# Best practices for Graph API calendar integration with Exchange Online/on-premises hybrid?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, hybrid

I am searching for a way to integrate (read and get change notifications) with user's calendars in an Exchange online/hybrid environment.

I have developed both EWS and Graph API integrations with Exchange on-premises and Exchange online for years. So far EWS has been working for hybrid environenments but as both EWS and basic authentication will soon deprecate I will need new solutions.

I have read a lot of articles and presentations about using MS Graph API to integrate with an Exchange hybrid environment with user mailboxes both in on-prem and int the cloud. But I'm not sure that I have got any wiser.

Most articles are about Exchange 2016 (what about Exchange 2019?) and they all say that the REST connection between Exchange Online and Exchange on-prem is in preview state. In addition it seems that change notifications is not supported.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for this?